# Android Crashlytics Eclipse: what to commit to git?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, crashlytics

I am very confused,

I am working with Eclipse (that is a requirement), switched to the new 
Crashlytics (Fabric) and now I am very confused about what should and what shouldn't be committed to git....

Please what are we supposed to add to git when we work with Crashlytics?

What should be excluded?

Comment: You don't have to commit Crashlytics code to the `git`. You can skip it completely

Answer (score 2):

*It's been a while I moved from Eclipse to IDEA, my answer might not true for your setting.*

Generally, your fabric plugin for eclipse does everything. So you don't have to do something.

You should exclude `fabric.properties` generated by fabric plugin. As I said, fabric plugin automatically add following lines to `.gitignore` where property file is located.

```
# fabric
fabric.properties
```

see https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html for further integration guide and https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/eclipse.html especially for eclipse

Anywho, don't forget its time to move Android Studio.